# I am finding div tag count after rendering HTML in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried following code snippet

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("some_url_link")
print(len(driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")))#728
time.sleep(30)
print(len(driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")))
```

It's giving me exact count of divs before rendering HTML=728
But same after 30 seconds i.e. 728
What's wrong here ?
Also i tried IMPLICIT_WAIT

Comment: this line `driver.get("some_url_link")` starts a page loading => it starts rendering => you call div counting after you start rendering, so everything goes as it should

Comment: @Dmitry Neledva Means the code will run correctly ?

Comment: yes, this code you post runs correctly, both div counters here should give you the same number. it's only if there is some slow js things is going to be executed after initial html rendering then you could get different numbers, but usually js changes nothing in html structure it just changes some data withing already existing html structure without touching things like `div`s .